Apache Ignite with Load from oracle Database 21c Warning Failed to load entries from db in multithreaded mode
Application upon trying to do cache.load() from Database Oracle 19c, we are getting warning printed in ignite logs
The Error is as follows
2024-08-29T20:34:05,391|WARN|mgmt-#111%ImportedCluster%|store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStore||Failed to load entries from db in multithreaded mode, will try in single thread [cache=OurCache, keyType=java.lang.Integer]
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:629) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:563) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1150) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:770) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:298) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:497) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:151) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:936) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareDefineBufferAndExecute(OracleStatement.java:1171) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1100) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLSelect(OracleStatement.java:1425) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1308) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3745) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3854) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1097) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar!/:21.6.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.loadCache(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:767) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheWriteBehindStore.loadCache(GridCacheWriteBehindStore.java:418) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:516) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.localLoadCache(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:515) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.localLoadCache(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:198) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5991) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJobV2.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:6040) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$TopologyVersionAwareJob.execute(GridCacheAdapter.java:6775) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeJobAdapter.call(ComputeJobAdapter.java:131) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1694) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$1.call(GridJobWorker.java:628) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:7498) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:622) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:547) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1367) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:2223) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1906) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1527) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5300(GridIoManager.java:242) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.execute(GridIoManager.java:1420) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:55) ~[ignite-core-2.16.0.jar!/:2.16.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

Details

There is no SQL Query Used in code, error appears just by calling .load() itself
Application works fine, but unable to comprehend what is cause for this warning

Definition
<bean
class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
<property name="name" value="ChnlMstrCache" />
<property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED" />
<property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC" />
<property name="backups" value="1" />

<property name="cacheStoreFactory">
<bean
        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory">
        <property name="dataSourceBean" value="dataSourceRM" />
        <property name="dialect">
                <bean
                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.dialect.BasicJdbcDialect">
                </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="types">
                <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcType">
                                <property name="cacheName" value="ChnlMstrCache" />
                                <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Integer" />
                                <property name="valueType"
                                        value="com.org.ChnlMstr" />
                                <property name="databaseSchema"
                                        value="app" />
                                <property name="databaseTable"
                                        value="chnl_mstr" />

                                <property name="keyFields">
                                        <list>
                                                <bean
                                                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                        <constructor-arg>
                                                                <util:constant
                                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.INTEGER" />
                                                        </constructor-arg>
                                                        <constructor-arg value="CHANNEL_ID" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="java.lang.Integer" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="channelId" />
                                                </bean>
                                        </list>
                                </property>

                                <property name="valueFields">
                                        <list>
                                                <bean
                                                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                        <constructor-arg>
                                                                <util:constant
                                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                        </constructor-arg>
                                                        <constructor-arg value="CHANNEL_NAME" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="channelName" />
                                                </bean>

                                                <bean
                                                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                        <constructor-arg>
                                                                <util:constant
                                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                        </constructor-arg>
                                                        <constructor-arg value="CREATED_BY" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="createdBy" />
                                                </bean>

                                                <bean
                                                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                        <constructor-arg>
                                                                <util:constant
                                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP" />
                                                        </constructor-arg>
                                                        <constructor-arg value="CREATED_ON" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="java.sql.Timestamp" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="createdOn" />
                                                </bean>

                                                <bean
                                                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                        <constructor-arg>
                                                                <util:constant
                                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                                                        </constructor-arg>
                                                        <constructor-arg value="MODIFIED_BY" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="java.lang.String" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="modifiedBy" />
                                                </bean>

                                                <bean
                                                        class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.JdbcTypeField">
                                                        <constructor-arg>
                                                                <util:constant
                                                                        static-field="java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP" />
                                                        </constructor-arg>
                                                        <constructor-arg value="MODIFIED_ON" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="java.sql.Timestamp" />
                                                        <constructor-arg value="modifiedOn" />
                                                </bean>
                                        </list>
                                </property>
                        </bean>
                </list>
        </property>
</bean>
</property>

<property name="readThrough" value="true" />
<property name="writeThrough" value="true" />
<property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>
<property name="writeBehindFlushFrequency" value="10000"/>
<property name="queryEntities">
<list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Integer" />
                <property name="valueType"
                        value="com.org.ChnlMstr"" />
                <property name="tableName" value="chnl_mstr" />
                <property name="keyFieldName" value="channelId" />

                <property name="keyFields">
                        <list>
                                <value>channelId</value>
                        </list>
                </property>

                <property name="fields">
                        <map>
                                <entry key="channelId" value="java.lang.Integer" />
                                <entry key="channelName" value="java.lang.String" />
                                <entry key="createdBy" value="java.lang.String" />
                                <entry key="createdOn" value="java.sql.Timestamp" />
                                <entry key="modifiedBy" value="java.lang.String" />
                                <entry key="modifiedOn" value="java.sql.Timestamp" />

                        </map>
                </property>

                <property name="aliases">
                        <map>
                                <entry key="channelId" value="CHANNEL_ID" />
                                <entry key="channelName" value="CHANNEL_NAME" />
                                <entry key="createdBy" value="CREATED_BY" />
                                <entry key="createdOn" value="CREATED_ON" />
                                <entry key="modifiedBy" value="MODIFIED_BY" />
                                <entry key="modifiedOn" value="MODIFIED_ON" />
                        </map>
                </property>
        </bean>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

Application On Startup
 ignite.cache("ChnlMstrCache").loadCache(null, new Object[0]);


Suggest you use the correct Oracle dialect instead of the "basic" one:
<property name="dialect">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
</property>

